# openssl_decrypt não responde dentro de uma function php

Tags: php, funções, openssl

São duas funções php, uma criptografa e a outra descriptografa o resultado da primeira, muito simples, mas a que descriptografa insiste em não responder nada, se eu colocar fora da função ela funciona, se jogo pra dentro não responde, alguém pode me dizer o que eu não estou sabendo sobre este caso?

```
$data = "Um texto a ser encriptado ";   
    
function encrypt($data) {  
                                                 
    //  require("sever/acess/get_securyt.php");
                                                     
                                            
    $key                    = "um codigo qualquer 0123456789 //* ";             
    $method                 = "aes-128-gcm";    
    $iv                     = "1111";   
    $tag                    = "25"; 
                                            
    echo $data; echo " << ok ele ta por aqui <br>"; 
    $encriptado             = openssl_encrypt(  
                                            $data,  
                                            $method,     
                                            $key,  
                                            $options = '0',  
                                            $iv,  
                                            $tag 
                                            );      

    echo "$encriptado << encriptado <br>";      
    $p6  = $encriptado[6]           ;                       
    echo "$p6 <<  pega a sétima posição<br>";       
    $data = $encriptado.$p6         ;   
    echo "$data <<  concatena e exibe o resultado final com uma letra a mais  <br>";
```

/* se eu jogar o código de descriptografar aqui dentro ele vai funcionar normalmente, mas se crio uma função pra ele, não funciona. */

```
return $data;                           
                                    
}


    echo "<br><br> Desencriptar <br>  ";    

    function desencrypt($data) {  
                                                     
//  require("sever/acess/get_securyt.php"); 
                                
$key                    = "um codigo qualquer 0123456789 //* ";             
$method                 = "aes-128-gcm";    
$iv                     = "1111";   
$tag                    = "25"; 
                                            
$datax                  = substr($data, 0, -1)  ;       

echo "$datax    << Tira a última, dentro da função desencriptar <br>"                           ;           
                                            
$datax  = openssl_decrypt( $datax, $method, $key, $options = '0', $iv, $tag ); // não ta obedecendo 
echo $datax; echo " resultado dentro de desencriptar  <br>";        
                                    
return $datax;  
                                            }

        
    
        // 
        $datax33 = encrypt($data);    
        echo "$datax33 <<< vindo da função encriptar   <br> "   ; 

        $form2 = desencrypt("$datax33")     ;    
        echo "$form2 << vindo da função desencriptar "  ;
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Este exemplo pode ser o que precisa. Mas eu faria uma classe:

```
   $plaintext = "message to be encrypted";

function encrypt($plaintext)
{
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher="AES-128-CBC");
    
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
    
    $key= 'abc123456';

    $ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    
    $hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, $key, $as_binary=true);
    $ciphertext = base64_encode( $iv.$hmac.$ciphertext_raw );
    return $ciphertext;

}

function decript($ciphertext)
{
    $c = base64_decode($ciphertext);
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher="AES-128-CBC");

    $key= 'abc123456';
    
    $iv = substr($c, 0, $ivlen);
    $hmac = substr($c, $ivlen, $sha2len=32);

    $ciphertext_raw = substr($c, $ivlen+$sha2len);
    $original_plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext_raw, $cipher, $key, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    return $original_plaintext;
}


echo encrypt($plaintext);
echo "\n";
$ciphertext = encrypt($plaintext);
echo "\n";
echo decript($ciphertext);
```